# Как реализовать запрос к БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Уважаемые, у меня такой вот вопрос. Как реализовать запрос к MySQL так, чтобы выводился не первый попавшийся подходимый параметр, а все. Если Вы меня не поняли, то взгляните на код:

```
$qwert="admin";
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM users WHERE class = '".$qwert."' LIMIT 10");
$userdata1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
print_r($userdata1);
```

Нужно получить полностью всю строку в массив. Спасибо.

Comment: а какой сейчас вывод?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($userdata1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) { print_r($userdata1); }
```